# Send IOT Hub messages to external DB

Tags: azure-eventhub, azure-iot-hub

I have IoT hub solution that messages from two devices, now as the IoT Hub data is deleted with 24 hours, I need to store that data in my MongoDB, How best to achieve this?
I have written a Event Hub function in Node JS and it works also but data never shows up in the DB.

```
module.exports = function(context, mySbMsg) {
context.log('Message received: '+ JSON.stringify(iotHubMessage));
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = 'mongodb:/abc.abc.abc.abc:27017/XYZ';
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
if (err) throw err;
console.log("Database connected!");
db.collection("IoTData").insertOne(mySbMsg, function(err, res) {
if (err) throw err;
console.log("1 document inserted");
db.close(); });});
context.done();};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested following code,it works.When you test the function app,you can track the logs.

```
module.exports = function (context, IoTHubMessages) {
    context.log('Message received:' + IoTHubMessages);

    var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

    var url = '{{Your mongoDb connection string}}';
    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {

            if (err) throw err;

            context.log("Database connected!");

            db.collection("IoTData").insertOne({IoTHubMessages:IoTHubMessages}, function(err, res) {
                    if (err) throw err;

                    context.log("1 document inserted");
                });
            db.close(); 
        }
    );

    context.done();
};
```